# addthis.com load button via ajax (to be able to set email variables dynamically)

Tags: javascript, ajax, object

i am trying to load and initialize the addthis.com widget via ajax in order to be able to reset the email variables inside the addthis_share object dynamically based on user input.

so far i am succeeding in loading the widget via ajax, but when i load it via ajax the button which i need the most is no longer part of the widget. this is very strange as i am using the exact same script to load both widgets.

the button which i need is the 'Email' button. the widget itself has two email buttons: one is called 'Email' and the other one is called 'Email App'. the 'Email' one is the one which accepts variables which are passed to emails (and the one which is not showing up when i load it via ajax). you can verify what email buttons are part of the widget after it loads by: clicking on the widget (on the + button itself) and typing 'email' in the search input field.

i have setup two js fiddles to illustrate the case. the first one loads the widget in the standard way (and you can see both email buttons there). the second one loads the widget via jQuery getScript and you can see that only the 'Email App' button shows up in it.

1) regular:
http://jsfiddle.net/FLAf4/

2) ajax:
http://jsfiddle.net/6QUWt/5/

i know that this is addthis.com specific question -- i tried posting this question on customization/q&a part of their website and so far nobody has commented on it. thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you cannot set pub-id and async on the addthis script, so you should set `#async=1` then set a global variable `addthis_config` that contains the publisher id, also you should have the `addthis_share` variable in the global scope and then assign the email template and email template variables to that global variable inside of the button click handler.

http://jsfiddle.net/joeflateau/Bht2b/4/

Comment: I agree, but this doesn't affect the problem which I outlined above, the Email button not showing up. I adjusted the AJAX fiddle (to have the addthis_share object be a global variable) and the Email button still doesn't show up.

Comment: might be a stupid question, but have you actually set up the "test_template" on AddThis.com?

Comment: yes, both variables are in the template and they work when i load the widget in the regular way. i also tried adding the async=1 parameter to the url. thanks.

Comment: ah HA! finally got it, check out the new fiddle i just posted

Comment: you should probably edit your answer to reflect the resolution. now that i 'accepted it' it looks like as if making the variable global was the resolution (unless you read the comments).

Comment: haha, if you are in the Central NY area in USA anytime just let me know, i've updated the answer to reflect the actual solution, cheers

Comment: super. yeah, if you are in manhattan feel free to retrieve your beer, too. i live downtown.